# How do I write custom code upon application quit?

Tags: objective-c, macos

So im trying to figure out how to run custom code when my application quits. Kind of like how I run awakeFromNib when the program starts to initiate certain items, im looking for the program quit equivilant so I can save the user interface state. Thanks.

Zach

UPDATE: Im not programmin in iOS, im trying to write a mac application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `applicationWillTerminate`, I think.

Comment: Yup... but... no guarantee that it'll be run.  The user might force quit your app or power off as they see fit.

Comment: @bbum is totally correct.  If your data is important, think about other options.

Comment: Just be aware that in iOS 4 applications will often not call `-applicationWillTerminate:`. They will call `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` and then be terminated as needed by the OS.

Comment: will applictaionWillTerminate work on mac applications? I'm not programming in iOS.

Comment: @Zachary yes, it's one of the methods on the `<NSApplicationDelegate>` protocol.  However, like @bbum pointed out, under certain circumstances it may not be invoked.

Comment: Oops, yes in OS X `-applicationWillTerminate:` will work however you probably want `-applicationShouldTerminate:` instead if you're planning to save state because you can retrun `NSTerminateLater`, perform time consuming work, and then call `-replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:` to terminate the app once your save is complete. See the NSApplicationDelegate docs for details.